# How to make a class factory to enables only certain properties of a object produced

Tags: c#, oop, factory

There's a factory `PizzaMaker.GetPizzaObject(PizzaNames pizzaName)` which accepts an `enum` name of one of the pizzas and returns a `Pizza` object, which stores the amount of each ingredient required in grams:

```
public class Pizza
{
    //the list of all possible properties of a class. Some class exemplars should have some of properties to be disabled.
    public int cheese { get; set; }
    public int ham { get; set; }
    public int pepperoni { get; set; }
}
```

Since not every type of pizza contains every type of ingredient I want my factory to enable only certain properties in the `Pizza` object, while the rest should be unavailablefor outside code (for any code for that matter).

My attempt at solution. General C&C welcome:

```
namespace Testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PizzaMaker pizzamaker = new PizzaMaker();
            Pizza newPizza  = pizzamaker.GetPizzaObject(PizzaMaker.PizzaNames.HamAndCheese);
            newPizza.cheese = 100;
            newPizza.ham = 80;
            newPizza.pepperoni = 100; // should throw an error, HamAndCheese shouldn't have "Pepperoni" available.
            
        }
    }

    public class PizzaMaker
    {
        //Enum containing all pizza types, used as an argument in PizzaMaker.GetPizzaObject factory
        public enum PizzaNames
        {
            pepperoniPizza,
            FourCheese,
            HamAndCheese
        }
        // class factory
        public Pizza GetPizzaObject(PizzaNames pizzaName)
        {
            Pizza result = pizzaName switch
            {
                PizzaNames.pepperoniPizza => CreatePizza(false, true), //pepperoni has no ham property, has cheese property
                PizzaNames.FourCheese => CreatePizza(false, false), //pizza four cheeses has neither ham, nor pepperoni
                PizzaNames.HamAndCheese => CreatePizza(true, false), //ham and cheese pizza has ham, but not pepperoni
            };
            return result;
        }


        private Pizza CreatePizza(bool hasHam, bool haspepperoni)
        {
            Pizza result = new Pizza();
            hasHam = true ? result.ham.DoSomething(); // somehow enable or disable the property based on wheither it has Ham,  pepperoni etc.
            haspepperoni = true ? result.pepperoni.DoSomething; // same
            // some initialization code, optional
            return result;
        }


    }
    public class Pizza
    {
        //the list of all possible properties of a class. Some class exemplars should have some of properties to be disabled.
        public int cheese { get; set; }
        public int ham { get; set; }
        public int pepperoni { get; set; }
    }
}
```

P.S. the `.DoSomething()` method is a placeholder for solution, because I suppose something should be done in that place in the code, but I don't know exactly what to do.

Comment: So you want `pizza` object to have `cheese`, `ham`, and `pepperoni` properties, but some of these properties should throw an exception when accessed? Sounds like minesweeper game. Can you provide some example of `pizza` usage after it's created?

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy maybe not the exception, but check wheither a certain property is available and only then do the code, otherwise - do nohing. Like iterate through the properties and only write to console the ingredients and amount if a certain property is allowed.

Comment: Use `Nullable<T>` properties, keep ingredients list, or even treat pizza as a dictionary of ingredients. Easy to check if an ingredient is available

Comment: `FourCheese` pizza should have `cheese` property enabled, `pepperoni` and `ham` disabled. `HamAndCheese` pizza should have `cheese` and `ham` enabled and `pepperoni` disabled etc.

Comment: Make the pizza type immutable (get only properties). Let the pizza maker initialize the entire pizza. It knows what is and is not allowed.

Comment: It's been 3 years since you asked this question and got two answers. Were any of the answers useful. Don't forget you can upvote any answer t h at was useful and you can accept an answer that you feel answered you question

Answer (score 0):

I think you are tackling this problem in the wrong way, it's better and more maintainable and less error-prone to have a  `BasePizza` class that contains common properties, then you create a derived class for each of your enum types where you put only properties specific to that Pizza Type.

```
public class BasePizza 
{
    // Common properties, like pizza type/name and size
     public PizzaNames Name{ get; set; }
    // public PizaSize Size { get; set; }
}
public class HamAndCheesePiza: BasePiza 
{
    public int Ham { get; set; }
    public int Cheeze{ get; set; }
}
public class PepperoniPiza: BasePiza 
{
    public int Pepperoni { get; set; }
}
public class FourCheese: BasePiza 
{
   // foorcheese related properties
}
```

next, you want your factory to return the `BasePizza` class, and in the caller's code you handle the type of the pizza accordingly. if you're using c# 7.0 or higher, the pattern matching using the `is` will make life easier for you: `expr is type varname`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PizzaMaker pizzamaker = new PizzaMaker();
        BasePizza newPizza  = pizzamaker.GetPizzaObject(PizzaMaker.PizzaNames.HamAndCheese);
        if(newPizza  is   HamAndCheesePiza hamAndCheesePiza)
         {
           hamAndCheesePiza.Ham = 99;
           hamAndCheesePiza.Cheese = 80;
         }
      // in the same way you treat other cases
        
    }
```

Comment: The thing is, there are probably more types of pizzas than the types of basic ingredients (at least in what I have in mind, I tbh made up the pizzas example for clarity, sorry). If I use basic inheritancee I have to write lots of repetitive code, when the only difference between classes is `ham=true; pepperoni=false; mushrooms=true` etc. I also have to keep  `ham` in one pizza exactly the same as `ham` in any other pizza so it would be handled the same way.

Comment: I don't know your exact usec ase and I answered based on the example you put in your question, I would still go with my solution since I perefer *Signle Responsability* over handling all logics in one God class! Things will get meessy very quickly by experience. For the repetitive code, you can still use this solution and refactor the common code using some *extension methods* or *helper classes*.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd take a different tack altogether.  I'd make a pizza a container to hold it's ingredients.  I'd also take advantage of the *collection initialization pattern* (make a class enumerable, give it an appropriate `void Add` method, and you can initialize it like a Dictionary)

Something like this:

First some enums:

```
public enum Ingredient
{
    Ham,
    Pepperoni,
    Pineapple,
    etc,
}

public enum SauceType
{
    Red,
    White,
}

public enum PizzaSize
{
    Personal,
    Small,
    Medium,
    Large,
    ExtraLarge,
}
```

then the Pizza class:

```
public class Pizza : IEnumerable<(Ingredient ingredient, int amountInGrams)> 
{
    private Dictionary<Ingredient, int> _ingredients = new Dictionary<Ingredient, int>();
    private SauceType _sauceType;
    private PizzaSize _size;

    public Pizza(SauceType sauceType, PizzaSize size)
    {
        _sauceType = sauceType;
        _size = size;
    }

    public void Add(Ingredient ingredient, int amountInGrams)
    {
        _ingredients.Add(ingredient, amountInGrams);
    }

    public IEnumerator<(Ingredient ingredient, int amountInGrams)> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var ingredient in _ingredients)
        {
            yield return (ingredient.Key, ingredient.Value);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public static void TestPizza()
    {
        var newPizza = new Pizza(SauceType.Red, PizzaSize.Medium)
        {
            {Ingredient.Ham, 200},
            {Ingredient.Pepperoni, 250}
        };

        foreach (var ingredient in newPizza)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Ingredient: {ingredient.ingredient} - {ingredient.amountInGrams} grams");
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the TestPizza method, I end up with this in the debug output:

```
Ingredient: Ham - 200 grams
Ingredient: Pepperoni - 250 grams
```

You might also want to have a mechanism to have a recipe (if it's a medium pizza, and it has Ham, then it's 200 grams, 350 grams if it's "Double Meat" (but, I'll leave that up to you)).

As to your "Pizza Maker" factory, just build a class that has a set of recipes (roughly a `Dictionary<string, (SauceType sauce, Dictionary<Ingredient, int>)>`) and when someone asks for a "The Works" pizza, you look up the recipe, build a pizza the way I showed above (except by explicitly calling `Add`) and returns the result.